# Can't understand this behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a simple notes app and delete isn't working properly, even though state is correctly updated.
The state is being updated correctly as I can see on the console.
But all the notes including and after that note that I click delete on are getting deleted on the DOM for some reason.
For example if I have 3 notes ["hello","hi","hey"], if I delete the second note("hi"), the state shows the correct notes ["hello","hey"] but  both "hi" and "hey" are deleted on the page not just "hi" like it was supposed to.
I can't understand where I've gone wrong, so I'd like to correct it.

App.js:

```
handleDelete = (note_id) => {
    const id = 'display-' + note_id;
    console.log(id);
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';//remove element

    //delete the note and update state
    const newNotesList = this.state.notesList;
    newNotesList.splice(note_id,1);
    this.setState({
      notesList : newNotesList
    })
    console.log(this.state.notesList)
  }
```

Display.js:

```
render(){
    const notesList = this.props.notesList;
    const displayNotes = notesList.map( (note,note_id) =>
      <div id={ 'display-' + note_id } className="display">
      {/*some code*/}
      <button type="button" className="delete-button"
     onClick = { () => this.props.handleDelete(note_id) } > Delete </button>
      </div> );

    return <div>{displayNotes}</div>;
  }
```

Comment: why, oh, why you have two ways of removing notes from the view and you apply both at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this

```
// don't mutation object

// App.js
handleDelete = (note_id) => {
    //delete the note and update state
    const newNotesList = this.state.notesList.filter((item, index)=> index !== note_id)
this.setState({
  notesList : newNotesList
})
  }

// Display.js
render(){
    const notesList = this.props.notesList;
    const displayNotes = notesList.map( (note,note_id) =>
      <div>
      {/*some code*/}
      <button type="button" className="delete-button"
     onClick = { () => this.props.handleDelete(note_id) } > Delete </button>
      </div> );

    return <div>{displayNotes}</div>;
  }
```

==== here is the reason ========

at first the `state.note` is ["hello","hi","hey"], in the function of `handleDelete` you delete "hi" and make the id of `dispaly-1`'s display become to hidden, so when react render the `state.note === ["hello","hey"]` the element of "hey"'s id become `dispaly-1` so "hey" will be hidden. you will only see "hello"

```
handleDelete = (note_id) => {
    // this.state.notesList === ["hello","hi","hey"]
    const id = 'display-' + note_id;
    console.log(id);
    // the problem is u hidden the next element

    // 1. newNotesList.splice(note_id,1);
    // 2. document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none'
    // two methods choose one or you will hidden two elements


    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';//remove element

    //delete the note and update state
    const newNotesList = this.state.notesList;
    
    newNotesList.splice(note_id,1);
    this.setState({
      notesList : newNotesList
    })
    console.log(this.state.notesList)

   // for example
   // the `this.state.notesList` new is ["hello","hey"]
  }


notesList.map( (note,note_id) =>
      // `note` is ["hello","hey"]  , u don't need hidden the `2rd` element
      //you have been delete 'hi' ` the id of `display-1`'s display ==='hidden' 
     // now "hey"'s id is `display-1`
      <div id={ 'display-' + note_id } className="display">
      {/*some code*/}
      <button type="button" className="delete-button"
     onClick = { () => this.props.handleDelete(note_id) } > Delete </button>
      </div> );
``
```

Comment: Avoiding mutation is certainly good, but why exactly would this solve the problem of multiple notes apparently getting deleted, do you know?

Comment: actually the problem is he delete 2rd element hidden `3rd` element @CertainPerformance

Comment: Curious, I thought that since no `key` was provided, the rendered `<div>`s (and their contents) would be re-created on every render call - so the hiding of `'display-' + note_id` wouldn't do anything, since the element would not exist on the next render. Wonder what's up.

Comment: actually the point is the element didn't bind with the `id` name, but the `id` name connected with index. as we know, `index` is "eval" ; )  so every render call, it will effect the `index` element's style   @CertainPerformance